# why does my code set values to the wrong view with listener

Tags: java, android

I have four Buttons that display the the date/time of calendars which are attributes of my activity. When a button is pressed, the according DatePickerDialog gets called which sets the values the users entered in the calendar object.

Though the identification of the calendars and dialogs seems correct, when I press "endDate" and click on ok in the dialog, startDate's text gets set.

Why does android behave like this and to fix this nonsense behaviour? (And yes, I cleaned and refreshed the project...)

Thank's in advance, you always surprise me guys :)

**UPDATE**
OK, now I got it, I set the MONTH in the onTimeSetListener fr startDate instead of the MINUTE; fixed the code
**/UPDATE**

Here's the listing:
this is a part of the attribute definition (I left out the Views)

```
static final int START_DATE_DIALOG_ID   = 0;
static final int START_TIME_DIALOG_ID   = 1;
static final int END_DATE_DIALOG_ID     = 2;
static final int END_TIME_DIALOG_ID     = 3;
```

this is the relevant part of the onCreate()

```
startDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startDate);
startTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startTime);
endDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.endDate);
endTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.endTime);
startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
[......]
startDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(START_DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
    startTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(START_TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
    endDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(END_DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
    endTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(END_TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case START_DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    startDateSetListener,
                    startCal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    case START_TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    startTimeSetListener,
                    startCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    startCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                    true); // is24hView
    case END_DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    endDateSetListener,
                    endCal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    endCal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    endCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    case END_TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    endTimeSetListener,
                    endCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    endCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                    true); // is24hView
        }
    return null;
}


private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener startDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        startCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        startCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        startCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                        updateDisplay(START_DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        }
;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener endDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        endCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        endCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        endCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                        updateDisplay(START_DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        }
;
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener startTimeSetListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                startCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                startCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                updateDisplay(START_TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        }
;
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener endTimeSetListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                endCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                endCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                updateDisplay(END_TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        }
;

// updates the date in the TextView
private void updateDisplay(int dialogId) {
   switch(dialogId){
        case START_DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            startDate.setText(getDateFromCal(startCal));
            break;
        case START_TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            startTime.setText(getTimeFromCal(startCal));
            break;
        case END_DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            endDate.setText(getDateFromCal(endCal));
            break;
        case END_TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            endTime.setText(getTimeFromCal(endCal));
            break;
    }
}

private String getDateFromCal(Calendar cal){
    return new StringBuilder()
            .append(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) .append(".")
            .append(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)    .append(".")
            .append(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))         .toString();
}
private String getTimeFromCal(Calendar cal){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int num = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    if(num<10)
        sb.append("0");
    sb.append(num);
    sb.append(":");
    num = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    if(num<10)
        sb.append("0");
    sb.append(num);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're updating the wrong display (`START_DATE_DIALOG_ID`) from your listener `endDateSetListener`.

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener endDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        endCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        endCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        endCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                        updateDisplay(START_DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        }
;
```

Also - may I make a suggestion? It is very rare that a language or library is ever the problem; never assume that it is. Jeff Atwood (one of the guys that started StackOverflow) has an excellent article on the subject: [First rule of programming: It's always your fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Comment: and thanks for the reference to that article, obviously I was not the only one who lost the overview over his/her code once in a while...

Comment: Happens *all* the time :-D Sometimes you just have to stop staring at it then go back and walk through what you're doing.